# How do I fix file access problems with Git Portable?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm using the latest version of git portable on windows. I configured access to my github repository with ssh keys. Everything works fine. The only quibble is the following error message I get everytime I push or pull:

```
hostfile_replace_entries: link /.ssh/known_hosts to /.ssh/known_hosts.old: Operation not permitted
update_known_hosts: hostfile_replace_entries failed for /.ssh/known_hosts: Operation not permitted
```

I don't know where this comes from or how to resolve it.

Comment: Your ssh program is printing these messages. Git's only involvement here is that it invokes an external (non-Git) ssh program, when using ssh to access another Git repository. You can control which ssh program Git runs, so if you have one that works completely, and one that works with complaints, you can stop the complaints by using the one that works completely: set `core.sshCommand` as needed. Otherwise, investigate your ssh program(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -Tv` to see at which point the error message is displayed.

`/.ssh/known_hosts` means Git consider $HOME is empty.
Because that file should be in `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`

For testing, set in your Windows User environment variables a HOME variable set to `%USERPROFILE%`.
Then try again from a new CMD session (new window).

Check if you have any `GIT_SSH` environment variable set.
You should use SSH from `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` or `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.